# Jquery mobile - Input and label are not in same lane in Jquery mobile version 1.2.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I follow documentation and add my label and input into same div with `data-role='fieldcontain'`with jquery and they are separete on page. Website: [site](http://testing3.ats-global.com//cz/cs/7_contacts.html) . Why it happens ? Thank you very much.

HTML before Jquery:

```
<div id="form" class=" ui-body ui-body-d">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Text</legend>
    <label>
      <label>Name</label>
      <label><input type='text' name='f_Fname' value= "" /></label>
    </label>
    ...more content here
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
   if($('input[type="text"]').parent().is('label')){
    $('input[type="text"]').unwrap();
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
        $(this).prev().addBack().wrapAll('<div data-role="fieldcontain">');
        $(this).prop('id', this.name)
           .prev('label').attr('for', this.name);
    })
   }
   if($('textarea').parent().is('label')){
    $('textarea').unwrap();
    $('textarea').each(function () {
        $(this).prev().addBack().wrapAll('<div data-role="fieldcontain">');
        $(this).prop('id', this.name)
           .prev('label').attr('for', this.name);
    })
   }
```

HTML after Jquery:

```
<div id="form" class=" ui-body ui-body-d">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Text</legend>   
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="f_Fname">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="f_Fname" name="f_Fname" value="" />
        </div>
        </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you wrapping each label and input in _label_? why dont you do it statically?

Comment: Hi omar it is in 1000 lanes of code from php where form is built for different languages i use jquery to remove them. It's not actualy form  its div with id form.

Comment: Should I progress with my jquery function or remove it and go back to that crazy php file ?

Comment: in your php file, make the final output simple and straight-forward, which doesn't require jQuery interference.

Comment: Omar that php doesn't make sense to me. I make it work with rules in css `#form input.ui-input-text, textarea.ui-input-text{ display: inline-block !important; width: 75% !important;}` and `#form [data-role='fieldcontain'] > label{display: inline-block !important;width: 25% !important;}`. What is disadvantage of this solution ?

Comment: You need to make sure it's responsive and can fit any screen resolution. Other than that, it should be fine :)